# EventHandler Duration and Asynchronous Execution

Tags: exception, asynchronous, begininvoke, eventhandler

Here are a few questions in regard with event handling:

***Question 1***

Principally, may event handler (UI or not) methods execute for a relatively long time?

***Question 2***

If event handling may anyway  take a lot of time in a given system, then this handling must, probably, be asynchronously performed, in order to avoid blocking the s/w. In this case, shall the class publishing this event asynchronously call all the registered handlers? Or may be it is better for this class to avoid any such assumptions, and have each handler, that takes a long time to execute, perform its massive work asynchronously, and immediately return without blocking?

***Question 3***

Anyway, when an event handler method is asynchronously called using BeginInvoke by the class publishing this event, is it a must to call the corresponding EndInvoke, and even take in account the possibility of an exception? Or may be it is better for the class raising the event to ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

***Answer to question 1***

See [jgauffin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20329076/2050703).
Basically, event handlers must perform in a relatively short time in order not to block the execution of the rest of the registered handlers, nor the handling of the following events. Needless to say, this demand becomes crucial when dealing with events whose handling holds the UI unresponsive!

***Answer to question 2***

Assuming that a class publishing an event isn't familiar with all possible event handlers (especially consider an event published by some DLL exported class), the class must call all the registered handlers asynchronously. But this has its cost (thread switching, caching, concurrency, synchronization, &c: see, for example, [Brannon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145420/2050703), [Manoj Sharma](http://www.somanyword.com/2014/03/common-problems-of-concurrency-multi-threading-in-java/), or even [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AvoidThreadsForOptimizations) wiki), which shouldn't be paid unless must be. Therefore the best alternatively is letting each registered handler, which, of course, knows how much time-consuming its own work is, decide whether it shall execute its own work synchronously or asynchronously. And here's a nice idea: an event may use its event-arguments structure to publish the time allocated for each handler (this time is basically calculated by dividing the overall event handling time permitted by the number of currently registered listeners), letting each handler use this info to decide whether to execute its own work synchronously or asynchronously.

***Answer to question 3***

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) (note "Important!"), [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620310/do-you-have-to-call-endinvoke-or-define-a-callback-for-asynchronous-method-ca/11620700#11620700) (a prominent world-class .NET expert), [Bruno Brant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620478/2050703), and eventually [STW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916095/how-do-i-make-an-eventhandler-run-asynchronously/1916241#1916241), which also supplies demo code; all of them seem to be strongly in favor of calling EndInvoke and catching possible exceptions. (Indeed, some programmers tend to avoid using exceptions, but exceptions are inherent with C++, Java, and .NET methods, and even more so with Python functions. If big-data s/w like Hadoop and the applications above it intensively use exceptions, then anyone may.)

***Postscript***

Eventually, after realizing that no one is going to reply my question, I turned to Microsoft's social MSDN, where I immediately received an answer from Magnus (also a prominent world-class .NET expert), which basically agreed with above arguments; see our correspondence [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff299d91-1eb5-4f36-920b-58ca496589e7/eventhandler-duration-and-asynchronous-execution?forum=csharpgeneral).